# Can the word "over" be replaced by "due to" or "because of"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

One day, I was surfing on the Oxford dictionary so as to look up the meaning of **over**, when I looked at its meaning, I saw the phrase *"I couldn't hear what he said **over** the noise of traffic"*. So the word "over" is used in this sentence. Can **over** be replaced by **due to**?

Comment: Not with exactly the same meaning, though these compound prepositions ('because of' and [though some hyperprescriptivists would disagree] 'due to') could be used instead, with the same general sense. '... could not hear X over Y' means that Y was too loud for X to be heard clearly (or even at all). 'Above' is an interchangeable synonym in this usage, as it often is for 'over'.

Comment: "Over" only describes the external circumstances, but it certainly yields an inference of causality as well.

Comment: The use of 'over' in 'I couldn't hear his voice over the noise of the traffic' does not mean 'due to' it means that the volume of his voice was less than that of the traffic. It is roughly analogous to 'I couldn't see my neighbour over the 2 metre wall between us'. That is the wall was too tall to see over.

Comment: 4 due to 2 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could say either

"I couldn't hear what he said over/above the noise of the traffic."  or

"I couldn't hear what he said due to/because of the traffic."

Any of those expressions would be perfectly understandable.

The first two, "I could not hear him over/above the traffic," implies that in order for "him" to be heard, "he" would have to make his voice louder than the traffic--his voice would have to rise above the noise of the traffic--in order to be heard by "I".

The second two combinations simply mean that the traffic was too loud--and "he" was too quiet compared to the traffic--for "I" to hear what he was saying.

So, while there may be slight differences in exact meaning, you could say any of these, and no one would be more correct than the other.